# Parent container only wraps children until edge of the screen when adding new child elements (IE 11 support preferred)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a ToDo-List with lists placed horizontally. Each list has a header on top and the lists overflow vertically.

I have a container with a y-scrollbar for that while the header stays fixed on top. Additionally I can add new lists horizontally. When x-scrolling to the right the whole page scrolls, so the headers stay aligned to the lists.

**Problem:** when I scroll to the right to see the overflow, the scrollbar does not extend to the new width accounting for the new child elements and moves to the left. The container's  max width stays at the screen width (e.g. 1920px). The new list elements stay hidden.

Please look at this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/planta/1e6bxc4o/32/)** for visualization. As you can see the scrollbar stays behind `content 5`, while `content 6` and `content 7` are hidden. 
I've tried various css properties like floating and clearing etc. A fixed width won't do for me.

Only thing that worked was calculating the new width dynamically with Javascript/JQuery, but then on wider list containers the y-scrollbar is hidden from the user. I want the scrollbar to be **always visible**.

```css
.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}

.lists-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 80%;
}

.header {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.list {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  height: 1000px;
}

.outer {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

  <div class="header-wrapper">

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 1</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 3</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 4</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 5</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 6</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 7</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="lists-wrapper">

    <div class="list">
      content 1
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 2
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 3
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 4
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 5
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 6
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 7
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: remove overeflow from `.lists-wrapper`

Comment: @TemaniAfif that would remove the list scrollbar or break the alignment to the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra wrapper that would have the width of the overflowing content:

```css
.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}

.lists-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.list {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  height: 1000px;
}

.outer {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}

.intermediate {
  display: inline-block; /* to make its width be the width of the content; */
  height: 100%; /* to make the children percentage height still work */
  vertical-align: top; /* to mitigate the possible artifacts of inline positioning */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

  <div class="intermediate">

  <div class="header-wrapper">

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 1</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 3</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 4</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 5</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 6</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 7</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="lists-wrapper">

    <div class="list">
      content 1
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 2
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 3
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 4
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 5
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 6
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 7
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks. works nicely. Got a followup question: Do you have an idea how I can keep the y-scrollbar always on the right edge of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your class `.outer` has a fixed width of `1000px`.
Every content beyond this `1000px` will not be displayed.

Removing the width on the `.outer` class worked for me.

Comment: that would remove the x-scrollbar for the `.outer` though. only the fiddle result-box scrolls then. I've made some small changes to the fiddle

Comment: You can add `width: fit-content;` to `.lists-wrapper`. But this css feature is not supported by all browsers: see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content)

Comment: I do need it to work for IE 11, but that's lower priority. `fit-content` seems to work here but on my full code it somehow doesn't. Do I need to pay attention to any other properties like floating elements, positions or flex items?

Comment: Floating elements or similar could definitely be a problem, but i can't really tell without the code.

Comment: Figured out what was diffrent on my end here. I had `flex: 0 0 270px`. When I give the element `min-width: 270px` then it behaves as expected